# Fast text rendering in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I would like suggestions as to how to render text quickly in OpenGL.

Currently, I am reading a true type font and dynamically generating a texture containing all the ASCII characters, for each font used, for each font size used. Each texture is generated just once and kept for later use.

During the draw phase, I draw everything line by line.

I have a static array on memory, compute the kerning ect, modify the vertex positions and texture coordinates for the line. Then I bind the corresponding texture and render the line.

Unfortunately this seems to be very slow. Is there a better way?

Comment: "Unfortunately this seems to be very slow." Define "very slow". This is the standard way text is rendered. Are you drawing the quads via immediate mode or something? We need to see your code to know whether you're just implementing it wrong or if it's something to do with your algorithm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Draw the rendered text to a texture, and then draw that texture to the screen.  Store the texture between frames. You need some management of deleting text that is no longer visible on screen, but this should be magnitudes faster.

Graphics libraries usually abstract this as a String class that, once you draw it to the screen remembers the texture it drew and invalidates it if the internal string changes.

Answer (score 10):

The best way IMO is to use [distance fields](https://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/apps/valve/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf). Will use less space, be fast, supports several nice text effects easily, and is pretty easy to implement ( especially since you've already seem to have the font -> texture parts ready ).

Comment: Also there already exists easy to use tools for [creating font texture and kerning data](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) and then [generating a distance field out of it](http://bitsquid.blogspot.it/2010/04/distance-field-based-rendering-of.html).

Answer (score 2):

This is very nice and fast library for rendering dynamic text using freetype & OpenGL: [freetype-gl](http://code.google.com/p/freetype-gl/)

Answer (score 1):

The [FTGL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ftgl/) library would probably provide everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a new opengl text rendering library [`freetype-direct-gl`](https://github.com/stonewell/freetype-direct-gl), it uses a freetype font outline to render the scaled font directly, so there is no need to create bitmap texture or do complex calculation in CPU.